# Mapeo de datos en flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo un problema con al momento de querer mapear los datos de mi api se queda en un bucle infinito del CircularProgressIndicator, he intentado varias cosas pero sigue sin funcionar he usado el logger.d(response.body) para comprobar que la api este funcionando correctamente y si esta funcionando correctamente.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:flutter_application_1/provider/menu_provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('SIN DATO'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Consumer<AdminProvider>(
                builder: (context, usersProvider, child) => usersProvider
                        .isLoading
                    ? const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.teal))
                    : Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: usersProvider.users?.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final user = usersProvider.users![index];
                            return Scaffold(
                              body: Drawer(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(user.descripcion),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

tengo hecho mi provider en el cual se realiza la peticion la url http:localhost:3000/menu, la cual contiene ciertos datos como "descripcion, id, orden" y aquellos son los que necesito mapear pero por alguna razon la peticion no se concreta y se queda con el CircularProgressIndicator.

```
class AdminProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final logger = Logger();

  List<MenuAdminDto>? _users;

  List<MenuAdminDto>? get users => _users;

  bool isLoading = true;

  Future getEnvios() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/menu'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    );

    logger.d(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final List<dynamic> data = json;

      _users = data.map((user) => MenuAdminDto.fromJson(user)).toList();

      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      throw Exception('no se completo la peticion');
    }
  }
}
```

y de igual manera tengo creado el Dto

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<MenuAdminDto> menuAdminDtoFromJson(String str) => List<MenuAdminDto>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => MenuAdminDto.fromJson(x)));

String menuAdminDtoToJson(List<MenuAdminDto> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class MenuAdminDto {
  MenuAdminDto({
    required this.id,
    required this.orden,
    required this.descripcion,
    required this.icono,
    required this.vista,
  });

  final int id;
  final int orden;
  final String descripcion;
  final String icono;
  final String vista;

  factory MenuAdminDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MenuAdminDto(
        id: json["Id"],
        orden: json["Orden"],
        descripcion: json["Descripcion"],
        icono: json["Icono"],
        vista: json["Vista"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Id": id,
        "Orden": orden,
        "Descripcion": descripcion,
        "Icono": icono,
        "Vista": vista,
      };
}
```

Comment: sabes si entra al if ? que valor retorna el response.statusCode ?

Comment: Por que hay un 'return scaffold' dentro de su itemBuilder? Deberia tener solo un 'return scaffold' en su 'Widget build'.